# Same color is displayed differently on CCLabel and CCSprite in CocosSharp (Cocos2D)

Tags: colors, xamarin, cocossharp

I'm using CocosSharp in Xamarin to display a label (`CCLabel`) and a sprite with a background color (`CCSprite`).
Both nodes have been assigned the same color value, but the colors are displayed differently on the device and in the simulator.

Has anyone else experienced the same issue?
I have tried other blending modes for the label without any luck.
Don't see a reason why the colors are displayed differently..

[image]

Comment: I had to resort to using atlas labels anyway, so it's not an issue for me anymore now. But still curious to know the answer to this question.